# GitHub Authentication from a WPF Application using Username & Password

Tags: c#, wpf, git, authentication, github

I'm developing a small WPF Application which will sit on top of a Local Git Repo.

It's a Line-Of-Business app to allow some business users to edit some files via a GUI and then push them back up to GitHub

I'm using the LibGit2Sharp libraries to handle all the git commands, but I'd also like to force the users to login to the application using their GitHub credentials everytime the application is loaded.

I've been looking at the OAuth2 libraries & some existing nuget packages (http://johnnycode.com/GitHubOAuth2Client/) but they all seem to revolve around a web based app, and require client id's and secret keys.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a simple API that will take a username & password and return a simple success/fail for the login attempt or am I stuck writing my own wrapper around the GitHub API

Comment: Can't you check if a user can authenticate using a simple `git status` on the repo that's going to be pushed to using the user's credentials?

Comment: That would only check locally in the cloned repo. what if permissions had been subsequently revoked on GitHub. Anyway, I figured it out... see solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a simple REST call to the older v2 API passing UserName & Password in the auth headers while requesting a specific repo. Then checking the permissions that came back on the requested Repo.

```
private class Permissions
{
     public bool Admin { get; set; }
     public bool Push { get; set; }
     public bool Pull { get; set; }
}

private class GitHubRepo
{
     public Permissions Permissions { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public bool Authenticate(string userName, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var apiUrl = "https://api.github.com/";
        var resource = "repos/myAccount/";
        var repoName = "myRepo";

        var client = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = apiUrl,
                Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password)
            };

        var request = new RestRequest {Resource = string.Join("", resource, repoName)};

        var response = client.Execute<List<GitHubRepo>>(request);
        if ((int) response.StatusCode >= 200 && (int) response.StatusCode < 209)
        {
            if (response.Data.Any(r => r.Name == repoName))
            {
                var repo = response.Data.Single(r => r.Name == repoName);

                if (repo.Permissions.Admin || (repo.Permissions.Pull && repo.Permissions.Push))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```